# Controller for a automotive BLDC triphasic motor that takes into account Velocity, Acceleration and jerk

Tags: motor-controller, control-theory, ac-motor

### Problem

Im in the autonomous driving department for formula student and due to the current pipeline the very last message that outputs from it is a message that contains Velocity, Acceleration and Jerk along with two others that are related to steering. Unfortunately our inverter only three different inputs Current and Motor Speed(RPMs) and a position for the motor.
For now although the inverter can brake a bit Im just worried with control for acceleration as braking would follow suit if the acceleration approach was resolved.

The initial idea was to implement a PID type controller. The thing is: Its always our approach and the values that come out of the message are already performed by a PID and before that the values that dictate that algorithm act like a synchronous linear clock which im afraid will make gains too track section specific(ie we can use all the calibration but as soon as the next sharp curve and broad curve appear our car will not act appropriately).

I've been looking into LQR's, Model Control, and other controller algorithms that take more environment information into account as i feel that the PID is too focused on only one variable. Although since they are so many yet most of the time people only focus on PID. It requires me to understand in depth each algorithm to see if they even are appropriate.

### TL;DR

Is there a controller theory algorithm that takes into account multiple parameters like Velocity, Acceleration and Jerk for its feedback and setpoint inputs and outputs a variable like Motor Power?

Im not asking for a full implementation, I've taken into consideration a informed PID, or multiple instances but im afraid they wouldnt cooperate as those three are very intertwined.